# Erro ao executar WebService Java

Tags: web-service, netbeans, soap, glassfish

Estou tentando executar um `Web Service` `SOAP` pelo servidor `GlassFish Server 4.1.1` no `NetBeans 8.2`. Ao tentar executar o seguinte erro é retornado:

Métodos do Web Service:

```
@WebService(serviceName = "CalculatorWS")
@Stateless()
public class CalculatorWS {

    @WebMethod(operationName = "hello")
    public String hello(@WebParam(name = "name") String txt) {
        return "Hello " + txt + " !";
    }

    @WebMethod(operationName = "add")
    public int add(@WebParam(name = "i") int i, @WebParam(name = "j") int j) {
        return i + j;
    }
}
```

Executo o Web Service da seguinte maneira:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém o seguinte erro é retornado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que devor fazer ?

Comment: Verificar se o serviço foi implantado corretamente, e se o servidor está em execução.

Comment: O servidor está iniciado

Comment: O WebResponde quando voce digita http://localhost:8080 no browser? E o que acontece se você digitar http://localhost:8080/CalculatorWS/CalculatorWS?Tester?

Comment: localhost:8080 no browser retorna "Your server is now running".

Comment: se eu digitar http://localhost:8080/CalculatorWS/CalculatorWS?Tester dá HTTP 404 - Not Found

Comment: Edite sua pergunta e poste a entrada da pagina CalculatorWS onde a pagina recebe os parametros.

Comment: postar o método você diz ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvido.

Tive que Implantar o Web Service. Fiz da seguinte maneira:

Cliquei com o botão direito em cima do Projeto e cliquei em Implantar, como segue a imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]